# I cannot view the image published by usb_cam

Tags: ros, camera, uvc-cam, usb-cam, cvbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ran the usb_cam node with `rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node` the images are published and i ensured that with `rostopic echo /usb_cam/image_raw`but when i tried running `rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw` to view the published images a blank (black) window pops up and image is not shown. how to fix it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213373/i-cannot-view-the-image-published-by-usb_cam/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2015-07-10**:
I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 and I don't have this problem with your commands.
Have you any warning or error messages ?
Is your camera connected to this port : /dev/video0 ?

**Comment by [quyetbui](https://answers.ros.org/users/76767/quyetbui/) on 2021-08-04**:
I'm in the same problem, could you tell me the way to fix this, pls!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend using `rqt_image_view`, I tried to execute this command as well but nothing is happening for me except the programm hangs in the console. I can not even terminate it with `CTRL-C`.

In rqt_image_view you can select the topic you want at runtime.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0